# UITableView in UITableViewController behind navigation controller on initial load

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationbar

On the initial load of my UITableViewController the first row gets hidden behind the navigation, but if I push to another view and return to this UITableViewController it is loaded correctly and the first row isn't obscured. I can not figure this one out.

Here's a screen shot of the initial load of the table and the one on the right is after I return from one of the views that was pushed by clicking a row

[image]

Here's my controller code:

```
class AccountInfoTableViewController: UITableViewController{

var delegate: AccountInfoTableViewDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.topViewController.title = "Account Info"
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    println("NAV BAR HEIGHT \(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)") // 44.0
// prints NAV BAR HEIGHT 44.0
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){
        delegate?.accountInfoTableRowClicked(cell.textLabel!.text!)
    }
}
```

}

POSSIBLE IMPORTANT NOTE:

This UITableViewController is used in a tab bar controller

Added some more detail and code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016261/swift-table-in-tabcontroller-only-is-positioned-correctly-if-its-the-first-tab)

Comment: Make sure your table view controller's `Adjust Scroll View Insets` is true. This can be found in Interface Builder in the Attribute Inspector tab for your view controller

Comment: @Bluehound yes, Adjust Scroll View Insets is checked

Comment: This is strange... Looks like both `Adjust Scroll View Insets` and `Extend Edges Under Top Bars` are unchecked... If you will not find a reason, you can try this: `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` (but only if your navigation bar will always be opaque)

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone had no effect

Comment: what about changing navigationBar.translucent flag??

Comment: @HMHero what do you mean changing it? setting it to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your other question, I'm wondering if it's the same issue with having the UITabBarController embedded within a UINavigationController. If that's the case, the  Just to recap again, the controller hierarchy should be as follows:

First UINavigationController -> First UITableViewController
Second UINavigationController -> Second UITableViewController
Finally, both of the above UINavigationControllers added to the UITabBarController's viewControllers array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yep, same issue - just posted some sample code in the other question. Thanks very much for your in depth answer, it opened my eyes to a few things I definitely did not grasp. Thanks Mark, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Is the UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController in the storyboard? Do this, and you should be golden. Have you tried manually adjusting the top content offset (via the storyboard) to 44?

Comment: No, I'm instantiating my views in code. I have tried adjusting the offset in code(viewDidLoad), which worked, but on return from a pushed view instead of being behind the navbar it's 44 away from the top of it. So I guess I mean it really didn't work :)