# Swift loading ViewController on TableViewCell Design

Tags: ios, swift

As I understand it, one of the best ways of handling opening Views upon clicking a particular tableViewCell is by pushing to the ViewController.

However, this apparently only works if you only embed the ViewController in a NavigationController.

Would you then have to embed each individual ViewController in an Navigation Controller?

This sounds sort of repetitive and tedious - is this good practice?

Comment: I've always been confused by this, to be honest. I have a navigation controller wrapped around all the view controllers in my storyboard, and I get the impression that at runtime it's really using one navigation controller instance, but that you kind of "opt in" to each view controller that you want to use that form of navigation for. Therefore a modal segue or something wouldn't be wrapped in a navigation controller.

Comment: Oh you can wrap around your view controllers with one navigation controller? Do you do this programmatically? I thought you needed to go to each one, and then create a new navigation embed for each individual controller

Comment: Well, I use the functionality built in to storyboards called wrap in navigation controller on each of my view controllers. I just suspect that there's really only one navigation controller at runtime. I don't know for sure if that's the case.

Comment: Oh, gotcha! New to Swift, but it seems like it's a bit of a stretch... there has to be a different way to do it

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1) uses navigation controllers on all of the view controllers, but doesn't really say why

I just use one navigation controller, and it works fine for me. I've used one and had segues between multiple viewControllers including several tables as well as using buttons in some places, and still been able to navigate super easily. In main.storyboard, just select the first view that's going to be a part of it, then go to Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller. Then, you just add in your segues (I believe they should all be Show(e.g. Push) segues to work correctly)
When running your app, there should be a bar at the top which can be used to go back (you can also edit the bar by adding other buttons or changing the color and title).

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) some documentation from apple

Comment: Recently, I've found embedding every view in a navigation controller is useful when using a tabBarCotroller alongside navigation controllers (see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994939/uitableview-in-uitableviewcontroller-behind-navigation-controller-on-initial-loa))